# RestHeart-replicaset - The connection string contains an invalid option 'readPreference&#61

Tags: restheart

I have RH 3.6 installed and I try to configure it to work with replicaset
but something is wrong because it doesn't work:

```
mongodb://user:password@ip:27017,ip:27017,ip:27017/?readPreference=primary&replicaSet=rsdigital&authSource=userManagement
```

Does anyone know what's wrong with the format?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesnt work"?

Comment: i tried to run the command :

Comment: java -server -jar /home/dsadm/restheart-3.6.0/restheart.jar /home/dsadm/restheart-3.6.0/etc/restheart_replica_dev.yml  --fork --envfile /home/dsadm/restheart-3.6.0/etc/replica_dev.properties

Comment: Exception in thread "main" org.restheart.ConfigurationException: wrong parameter mongo-uri
        at org.restheart.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:868)
        at org.restheart.Bootstrapper.loadConfiguration(Bootstrapper.java:198)
        at org.restheart.Bootstrapper.main(Bootstrapper.java:145)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The connection string contains an invalid option 'replicaSet&#61;rsdigital'. 'replicaSet' is missing the value delimiter eg 'replicaSet=value'
        at com.mongodb.ConnectionString.....

Comment: Please add all information to the question itself, not to the comment section. Additionally, where do these values come from?

Comment: Hi, you are apparently using the new configuration properties feature that unfortunately has a bug with escaping characters. Please check the below answer by Andrea Di Cesare (https://stackoverflow.com/a/54351223/615095), but the fix is available in release 3.7.0 only (https://github.com/SoftInstigate/restheart/releases/tag/3.7.0). Alternatively, you can edit your yaml configuration file (usually called restheart.yml) to use triple instead of double curly braces.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting the mongo-uri in the env properties file.
The mongo-uri variable in the yml configuration file is defined as `{{mongo-uri}}`. This way special chars (as the equal sign =) are escaped leading to the error.

Just define the variable as `{{{mongo-uri}}}` to fix it.

The conf file is being fixed (with triple `{{{var}}}` declarations) in upcoming RESTHeart version 3.6.3

More information on https://github.com/SoftInstigate/restheart/issues/327